# Creating custom control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a custome control in asp.net like this:

`<my:mycontrol id="myid" runat="server"></my:control>`

I have created a class like this:

```
public class mycontrol : Control, INamingContainer {}
```

but how can i use it like i mentioned above 
How can I recreate it so that I can declare it as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the user control at top of page or in web.config

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="my" TagName="mycontrol" Src="~/usercontrols/mycontrol.ascx" %>
```

for web.config (this means you can use it on any page without re-registering everytime, just add to your pages/controls section in system.web

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="my" src="~/usercontrols/mycontrol.ascx" tagName="mycontrol"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Ahh, forgot about the web.config way of doing this globally. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your control, in an ASPX page, have this at the top somewhere:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="my" TagName="mycontrol" Src="Controls/mycontrol.ascx" %>
```

Make sure the `Src` path to the ASCX file is correct and you should be OK.

Comment: Do I need to make it ascx or cs will also work ? I am creating control in code behing using C#

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx).